# How do EDMFunction work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We had a developer who attempted to filter on a numeric ID property using a string:

```
var student = (from s in dbStudents
        where s.StudentId.ToString() == "2" 
        select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

This won't work, as `ToString()` cannot be translated into SQL by the EF Provider.

One solution was provided works, but I honestly am unclear about why it works:

```
[EdmFunction("SqlServer", "STR")]
public static string ConvertToString(double? number)
{
   return number.HasValue ? number.ToString() : null;
}
```

And the query now looks like:

```
var student = (from s in Students
        where ConvertToString((double) s.LanguageId).Trim() == "2" 
        select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

My understanding is this query should be building up an expression tree, but it appears that we have a CLR method being executed in the middle? I had thought that we could only use methods where the provider understood how it could be translated into SQL.

The SQL looks right, can anyone tell me how we got from:

```
return number.HasValue ? number.ToString() : null;
```

to

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Student] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'2' = (LTRIM(RTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent1].[StudentId] AS float)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EdmFunction` attribute calls the specified method in SQL. The implementation you have in C# will be ignored. So in your case [`STR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) method is called at SQL end.

You can have your method as:

```
[EdmFunction("SqlServer", "STR")]
public static string ConvertToString(double? number)
{
   throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");  
}
```

and still it would work.

See: [EDM and Store functions exposed in LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx)

> **How it works**
>
> When a method with the EdmFunction attribute is detected within a LINQ
>   query expression, its treatment is identical to that of a function
>   within an Entity-SQL query. Overload resolution is performed with
>   respect to the EDM types (not CLR types) of the function arguments.
>   Ambiguous overloads, missing functions or lack of overloads result in
>   an exception. In addition, the return type of the method must be
>   validated. If the CLR return type does not have an implicit cast to
>   the appropriate EDM type, the translation will fail.

As a side note, you can also use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) like:

```
var student = (from s in Students
        where  SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) s.LanguageId)).Trim() == "2" 
        select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

The Entity Framework uses only the information in the attribute to convert the method call to SQL. The implementation is not used in this case.