# How to use sql server ISJSON function in linq query C# EF6 Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-function

I need to retrieve data from a table stored in SQL server, this table has json string column, then i need to retrieve only rows with a valid json column using linq in C# like that:

```
var q = from t1 in DBContext.table1 join  
        t2 in DBContext.table2 on t1.id equals t2.tId
        where 
        //Here what i need to use isJson like that but SqlFunctions does not contain it
        SqlFunctions.IsJson(t1.jsonTxt)
       select new resDTO
        {
          name=t1.name,
          details =t2.details 
        }
```

Comment: Which database, which ORM, what is `tables`?.

Comment: Simplest way is to create a view or table-valued function that filters the desired rows and use that as the basis.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv what is the need of (which database) it is local DB stored in sql server and the code with dummy names just for explanation what i need to do, how these info you asked for will affect the answer?

Comment: @JeroenMostert i need to do that using linq only , as i don't have the authority to change in sql server directly , so i am trying to do using linq only

Comment: So answer another question. Which ORM?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF6 database first

Comment: Never used EF6, check [EdmFunctionAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864689/10646316), looks like it is how old EF works with defining custom functions for LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to check for a valid Json string in your where clause. In that case you can do this I believe.

```
var q = from t1 in DBContext.table1 join  
    t2 in DBContext.table2 on t1.id equals t2.tId
    let isValid = IsValidJson(t1.jsonTxt)
    where isValid == true
   select new resDTO
    {
      name=t1.name,
      details =t2.details 
    }

   private bool IsValidJson(string strInput)
   {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strInput)) { return false;}
     strInput = strInput.Trim();
     if ((strInput.StartsWith("{") && strInput.EndsWith("}")) || //For object
         (strInput.StartsWith("[") && strInput.EndsWith("]"))) //For array
      {
        try
        {
           var obj = JToken.Parse(strInput);
           return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
     else
      {
       return false;
      }
   }
```

The method is from this thread:
[How to make sure that string is valid JSON using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net)

Comment: I already tried this solution but it gives me this error :
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsValidJson(System.string)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
RemoteStackIndex: 0`

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use let to get around the method